# absolute center horizontal, negative margin, IE6

Tags: html, css, position, internet-explorer-6, css-position

Using negative margin to put an element at center works fine in all modern browsers, who support it.

But in IE6, what can we do?

For example, this code fails in IE6:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    background: skyblue;
}

#child{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    top: 25px;
    background: orange;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmLJv/2/).

Comment: Just wondering, why are you wasting time developing for IE6? [It's older than your grandpa.](http://ie6isolderthanyourgrandpa.com/)

Comment: Isn't this why Google still uses the <center> tag on their main page?

Comment: @boj: I know that, but my client wants it. He has some IE6 users in his network... :(

Comment: @kikio I feel sorry for you.

Comment: @Louis: Does `<center>` any effect on absolute positioned elements?

Comment: I agree, I have a few clients that still use IE6 as well. It's a strange world we live in :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to your specific scenario but can you try using margins and padding rather than positioning?

```
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    background: skyblue;
}

#child{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: orange;
}
```